# Console program does not execute correctly when run from SciTE

Tags: c, scite

I'm learning C from a tutorial concurrently with a general programming course. The course setup advised Windows users to use SciTE, so I did. Possibly because I have Windows 8, I had to edit the SciTE cpp.properties file to get the sample programs to run. This is what the make/go section of the properties file looks like:

```
ccopts=-pedantic -Os
cc=g++ $(FileNameExt) -o $(FileName).exe
ccc=gcc $(FileNameExt) -o $(FileName).exe

make.command=make
command.compile.*.c=$(ccc) -std=c99
command.build.*.c=$(make.command)
command.build.*.h=$(make.command)
command.clean.*.c=$(make.command) clean
command.clean.*.h=$(make.command) clean
command.go.*.c=$(FileName)
```

My problem is that I cannot get this one program to execute in SciTE. It works fine in PowerShell/cmd but if I try to execute it in SciTE, I don't get the first printout and providing input does nothing. It also never ends, even if I stop executing. I have to go into task manager and end the program. I have had this problem before, but that was because I mistyped. I don't know what I've mistyped here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int num1;
    int num2;
    printf("Enter 2 numbers\n");
    scanf("%d%d", &num1, &num2);

    if(num1 == num2) {
        printf("they are equal\n");
    }

    if(num1 < num2) {
        printf("%d is less than %d\n", num1, num2);
        }

    if(num1 > num2) {
        printf("%d is greater than %d\n", num1, num2);
        }

    getch();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SciTE's output pane is not a regular console as you would expect - you can not ask for user input in SciTE's output pane.

However you can perhaps make use of [parameters](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTEDoc.html#Parameters) and slightly change you script to accept parameters instead user input.

Another option is use of other then default [subsystem](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTEDoc.html#CommandSubsystem) for go command:

```
command.compile.*.c=gcc $(FileNameExt) -o $(FileName).exe
command.go.*.c="$(FileDir)\$(FileName).exe"
command.go.subsystem.*.c=2
```

You can paste this block at the end of you `cpp.properties` if you wish to try it. Even more if you would like a Go command that compiles on the fly and executes, append this line to above block:

```
command.go.needs.*.c=gcc $(FileNameExt) -o $(FileName).exe
```

Side note: You can always terminate running SciTE program with `Ctrl+Break` or with "Tools > Stop executing" menu command.